# Update Postgres table using Ecto/Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have been learning Elixir lately and am wondering what is the correct syntax for solving my current issue. I am trying to update a model using Elixir and this update includes adding a value to the current value (ie amount = amount + passed_amount) and pushing a new value to an ecto array (ie transactions ++ new_transaction). Here is my latest attempt at doing this:

```
def add_transaction(conn, %{"coin" => coin_params}) do
        coin = Repo.get_by!(WalletCoin, ticker: coin_params["ticker"])
        coin["transactions"] ++ coin_params["transaction"]
        coin["amount"] = coin["amount"] + coin_params["amount"]
        case Repo.update(coin) do
            {ok, _coin} ->
              coins = Repo.all(WalletCoin)
              render conn, "index.json", coins: coins
        end
end
```

My intentions of asking this question was to get the answer and hopefully get some insight into Elixir best practices for doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in Elixir are immutable. You can't just assign a new value to a field in a map like that. You'll first need to create a changeset and then change the two values:

```
coin =
  Repo.get_by!(WalletCoin, ticker: coin_params["ticker"])

coin = coin
  |> Ecto.Changeset.change()
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:transactions, coin.transactions ++ coin_params["transaction"])
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:amount, coin.amount + coin_params["amount"])
```

Calling `Repo.update` with this should now work.

Comment: Hmm that didn't work, is there anything that I need to add to it for my case?

Comment: Ah right. `update_change` won't work. Can you try the edited code? I don't have Ecto set up locally to test but I think this should work.

Comment: Yup, your answer seems to be working so I marked it as the answer. However, i think i am having trouble adding to the Array of :float's. Do you know how to solve this: (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Type.array/4
        (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:896: Ecto.Type.array(4531.0, :float, #Function<9.63004218/2 in Ecto.Type.process_dumpers/3>, [2385.0]) ?